# Parameter type issue of FaIcon in Flutter

Tags: kotlin, dart

```
     final FaIcon? icon;
      const ButtonWidget({
        super.key,
        this.icon,
      });

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
            children: [
              FaIcon(icon) // "The argument type 'FaIcon?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData?',),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I defined the value named icon as FaIcon. But to me; The argument type 'FaIcon?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData? Gives a fault.

Answer (score 0):

"FaIcon" take as the first unnamed parameter an "IconData?" not another instance of "FaIcon" (see https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/blob/master/lib/src/fa_icon.dart).

You should do something like that:

```
final IconData? icon;
```

or

```
FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.THE_ICON_YOU_WANT),
```

Comment: Here's the thing, where I use FaIcon is my own widget. When I call this widget on the homepage or anywhere I want to use it and add the "icon" parameter and give this parameter the value FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.add) I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, you just need to change the type of "icon" in your widget to "IconData?".

Comment: I already added it. final IconData? icon; I added as

Answer (score 0):

Changed `final FaIcon? icon`; to `final FaIcon icon;`

after that change `this.icon =FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.home)`//default icon

Remove `FaIcon(icon)` and add `icon`  in the children